# VMWare Fusion: vmnet1 and vmnet8 not showing up after install Fusion 8.x or 10.x on Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, nat, ifconfig, vmware-fusion

After installing Fusion 8.x and 10.x, I cannot find the vmnet1 and vmnet8 at all.

When I do

```sh
sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli -c
```

This is what I got:

```
Configuring Bridged network vmnet0  
Configuring hostonly network vmnet1, probing for unused subnet ...  
Configuring NAT network vmnet8, probing for unused subnet ...  
Failed to create DHCP configuration file for network vmnet1  
Failed to create DHCP configuration file for network vmnet8  
Failed to configure default network settings  
Stopped all configured services on all networks
```

There is something really wrong. Could you please help?

Below is my /dev

```
crw-------  1 root  wheel           18,   1 Oct 17 16:57 afsc_type5
crw-------  1 root  wheel           10,   0 Oct 17 16:57 auditpipe
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel            9,   4 Oct 17 16:57 auditsessions
crw-------  1 root  wheel           31,   0 Oct 17 16:58 autofs
crw-------  1 root  wheel           35,   0 Oct 17 16:58 autofs_control
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           34,   2 Oct 17 16:58 autofs_homedirmounter
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           33,   2 Oct 17 16:58 autofs_notrigger
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           32, 0x0000019e Oct 17 16:58 autofs_nowait
crw-------  1 root  wheel           23,   0 Oct 17 16:58 bpf0
crw-------  1 root  wheel           23,   1 Oct 17 16:57 bpf1
crw-------  1 root  wheel           23,   2 Oct 17 16:58 bpf2
crw-------  1 root  wheel           23,   3 Oct 17 16:57 bpf3
crw-------  1 hoc   staff            0,   0 Oct 17 16:58 console
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           21,   5 Oct 17 16:58 cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           21,   3 Oct 17 16:58 cu.MALS
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           21,   1 Oct 17 16:58 cu.SOC
brw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   0 Oct 17 16:57 disk0
brw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   1 Oct 17 16:57 disk0s1
brw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   2 Oct 17 16:57 disk0s2
brw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   3 Oct 17 16:57 disk1
brw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   4 Oct 17 16:57 disk1s1
brw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   5 Oct 17 16:57 disk1s2
brw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   6 Oct 17 16:57 disk1s3
brw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   7 Oct 17 16:57 disk1s4
br--r-----  1 hoc   staff            1,   8 Oct 17 16:59 disk2
br--r-----  1 hoc   staff            1,   9 Oct 17 16:59 disk2s1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           24,   7 Oct 17 16:57 dtrace
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           25,   0 Oct 17 16:57 dtracehelper
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            0,   0 Oct 17 16:57 fbt
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel                 0 Oct 17 16:57 fd
crw-r--r--  1 root  wheel           13,   0 Oct 17 16:57 fsevents
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           19,  16 Oct 17 17:02 io8log
cr--r--r--  1 root  wheel           19,   9 Oct 17 16:57 io8logmt
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           19,  17 Oct 17 17:08 io8logtemp
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            0,   0 Oct 17 16:57 lockstat
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            0,   0 Oct 17 16:57 machtrace
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            3,   2 Oct 17 17:08 null
crw-------  1 root  wheel            7,   0 Oct 17 16:57 oslog
crw-------  1 root  wheel            8,   0 Oct 17 16:57 oslog_stream
crw-------  1 root  wheel           11,   0 Oct 17 16:57 pf
crw-------  1 root  wheel           11,   1 Oct 17 16:57 pfm
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            0,   0 Oct 17 16:57 profile
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  tty             15,   1 Oct 17 17:08 ptmx
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   0 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   1 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   2 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   3 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   4 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   5 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   6 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   7 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   8 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,   9 Oct 17 16:57 ptyp9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  10 Oct 17 16:57 ptypa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  11 Oct 17 16:57 ptypb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  12 Oct 17 16:57 ptypc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  13 Oct 17 16:57 ptypd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  14 Oct 17 16:57 ptype
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  15 Oct 17 16:57 ptypf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  16 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  17 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  18 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  19 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  20 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  21 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  22 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  23 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  24 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  25 Oct 17 16:57 ptyq9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  26 Oct 17 16:57 ptyqa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  27 Oct 17 16:57 ptyqb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  28 Oct 17 16:57 ptyqc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  29 Oct 17 16:57 ptyqd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  30 Oct 17 16:57 ptyqe
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  31 Oct 17 16:57 ptyqf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  32 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  33 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  34 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  35 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  36 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  37 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  38 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  39 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  40 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  41 Oct 17 16:57 ptyr9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  42 Oct 17 16:57 ptyra
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  43 Oct 17 16:57 ptyrb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  44 Oct 17 16:57 ptyrc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  45 Oct 17 16:57 ptyrd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  46 Oct 17 16:57 ptyre
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  47 Oct 17 16:57 ptyrf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  48 Oct 17 16:57 ptys0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  49 Oct 17 16:57 ptys1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  50 Oct 17 16:57 ptys2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  51 Oct 17 16:57 ptys3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  52 Oct 17 16:57 ptys4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  53 Oct 17 16:57 ptys5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  54 Oct 17 16:57 ptys6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  55 Oct 17 16:57 ptys7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  56 Oct 17 16:57 ptys8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  57 Oct 17 16:57 ptys9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  58 Oct 17 16:57 ptysa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  59 Oct 17 16:57 ptysb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  60 Oct 17 16:57 ptysc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  61 Oct 17 16:57 ptysd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  62 Oct 17 16:57 ptyse
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  63 Oct 17 16:57 ptysf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  64 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  65 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  66 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  67 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  68 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  69 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  70 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  71 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  72 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  73 Oct 17 16:57 ptyt9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  74 Oct 17 16:57 ptyta
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  75 Oct 17 16:57 ptytb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  76 Oct 17 16:57 ptytc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  77 Oct 17 16:57 ptytd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  78 Oct 17 16:57 ptyte
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  79 Oct 17 16:57 ptytf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  80 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  81 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  82 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  83 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  84 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  85 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  86 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  87 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  88 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  89 Oct 17 16:57 ptyu9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  90 Oct 17 16:57 ptyua
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  91 Oct 17 16:57 ptyub
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  92 Oct 17 16:57 ptyuc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  93 Oct 17 16:57 ptyud
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  94 Oct 17 16:57 ptyue
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  95 Oct 17 16:57 ptyuf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  96 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  97 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  98 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5,  99 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 100 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 101 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 102 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 103 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 104 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 105 Oct 17 16:57 ptyv9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 106 Oct 17 16:57 ptyva
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 107 Oct 17 16:57 ptyvb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 108 Oct 17 16:57 ptyvc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 109 Oct 17 16:57 ptyvd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 110 Oct 17 16:57 ptyve
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 111 Oct 17 16:57 ptyvf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 112 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 113 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 114 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 115 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 116 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 117 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 118 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 119 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 120 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 121 Oct 17 16:57 ptyw9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 122 Oct 17 16:57 ptywa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 123 Oct 17 16:57 ptywb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 124 Oct 17 16:57 ptywc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 125 Oct 17 16:57 ptywd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 126 Oct 17 16:57 ptywe
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            5, 127 Oct 17 16:57 ptywf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           14,   0 Oct 17 16:57 random
crw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   0 Oct 17 16:57 rdisk0
crw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   1 Oct 17 16:57 rdisk0s1
crw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   2 Oct 17 16:57 rdisk0s2
crw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   3 Oct 17 16:57 rdisk1
crw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   4 Oct 17 16:57 rdisk1s1
crw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   5 Oct 17 16:57 rdisk1s2
crw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   6 Oct 17 16:57 rdisk1s3
crw-r-----  1 root  operator         1,   7 Oct 17 16:57 rdisk1s4
cr--r-----  1 hoc   staff            1,   8 Oct 17 16:59 rdisk2
cr--r-----  1 hoc   staff            1,   9 Oct 17 16:59 rdisk2s1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            0,   0 Oct 17 16:57 sdt
lr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel                 0 Oct 17 16:57 stderr -> fd/2
lr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel                 0 Oct 17 16:57 stdin -> fd/0
lr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel                 0 Oct 17 16:57 stdout -> fd/1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            0,   0 Oct 17 16:57 systrace
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            2,   0 Oct 17 17:01 tty
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           21,   4 Oct 17 16:58 tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           21,   2 Oct 17 16:58 tty.MALS
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           21,   0 Oct 17 16:58 tty.SOC
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   0 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   1 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   2 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   3 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   4 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   5 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   6 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   7 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   8 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,   9 Oct 17 16:57 ttyp9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  10 Oct 17 16:57 ttypa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  11 Oct 17 16:57 ttypb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  12 Oct 17 16:57 ttypc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  13 Oct 17 16:57 ttypd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  14 Oct 17 16:57 ttype
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  15 Oct 17 16:57 ttypf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  16 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  17 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  18 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  19 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  20 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  21 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  22 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  23 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  24 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  25 Oct 17 16:57 ttyq9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  26 Oct 17 16:57 ttyqa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  27 Oct 17 16:57 ttyqb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  28 Oct 17 16:57 ttyqc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  29 Oct 17 16:57 ttyqd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  30 Oct 17 16:57 ttyqe
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  31 Oct 17 16:57 ttyqf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  32 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  33 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  34 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  35 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  36 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  37 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  38 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  39 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  40 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  41 Oct 17 16:57 ttyr9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  42 Oct 17 16:57 ttyra
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  43 Oct 17 16:57 ttyrb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  44 Oct 17 16:57 ttyrc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  45 Oct 17 16:57 ttyrd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  46 Oct 17 16:57 ttyre
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  47 Oct 17 16:57 ttyrf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  48 Oct 17 16:57 ttys0
crw--w----  1 hoc   tty             16,   0 Oct 17 17:08 ttys000
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  49 Oct 17 16:57 ttys1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  50 Oct 17 16:57 ttys2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  51 Oct 17 16:57 ttys3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  52 Oct 17 16:57 ttys4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  53 Oct 17 16:57 ttys5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  54 Oct 17 16:57 ttys6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  55 Oct 17 16:57 ttys7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  56 Oct 17 16:57 ttys8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  57 Oct 17 16:57 ttys9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  58 Oct 17 16:57 ttysa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  59 Oct 17 16:57 ttysb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  60 Oct 17 16:57 ttysc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  61 Oct 17 16:57 ttysd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  62 Oct 17 16:57 ttyse
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  63 Oct 17 16:57 ttysf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  64 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  65 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  66 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  67 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  68 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  69 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  70 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  71 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  72 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  73 Oct 17 16:57 ttyt9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  74 Oct 17 16:57 ttyta
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  75 Oct 17 16:57 ttytb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  76 Oct 17 16:57 ttytc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  77 Oct 17 16:57 ttytd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  78 Oct 17 16:57 ttyte
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  79 Oct 17 16:57 ttytf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  80 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  81 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  82 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  83 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  84 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  85 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  86 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  87 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  88 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  89 Oct 17 16:57 ttyu9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  90 Oct 17 16:57 ttyua
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  91 Oct 17 16:57 ttyub
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  92 Oct 17 16:57 ttyuc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  93 Oct 17 16:57 ttyud
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  94 Oct 17 16:57 ttyue
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  95 Oct 17 16:57 ttyuf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  96 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  97 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  98 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4,  99 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 100 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 101 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 102 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 103 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 104 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 105 Oct 17 16:57 ttyv9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 106 Oct 17 16:57 ttyva
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 107 Oct 17 16:57 ttyvb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 108 Oct 17 16:57 ttyvc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 109 Oct 17 16:57 ttyvd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 110 Oct 17 16:57 ttyve
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 111 Oct 17 16:57 ttyvf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 112 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw0
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 113 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 114 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw2
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 115 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 116 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw4
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 117 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw5
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 118 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw6
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 119 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw7
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 120 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw8
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 121 Oct 17 16:57 ttyw9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 122 Oct 17 16:57 ttywa
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 123 Oct 17 16:57 ttywb
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 124 Oct 17 16:57 ttywc
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 125 Oct 17 16:57 ttywd
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 126 Oct 17 16:57 ttywe
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            4, 127 Oct 17 16:57 ttywf
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           22,   1 Oct 17 16:58 uart.BLTH
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           22,   2 Oct 17 16:58 uart.MALS
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           22,   0 Oct 17 16:58 uart.SOC
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           14,   1 Oct 17 16:57 urandom
crw-rw----  1 root  _windowserver   20,   0 Oct 17 16:57 xcpm
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            3,   3 Oct 17 16:57 zero
```

Comment: having same issue did you resolve this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging this through I found the issue was with security and privacy settings on mac high sierra, when you Install vmware 10 0r 8 in security and privacy options(general tab) on mac you would not see " Allow  Vmware " option for this to happen.

run this command `Sudo spctl --master-disable` and restart the system.
After that reinstall Vmware and you should see this option in "Security and privacy | general tab ".

Note: while installing Vmware if you keep the "security and privacy" window open you will not see this updated you have close it and open it again.

Tested this with Vmware 8.0.0 & VMware 10 it works ( mac High sierra v 10.13.2 )

Comment: Solved the issue on my High Sierra 10.13.6 with VMware Fusion 8.5.10

Comment: This solved the problem on High Sierra 10.13.6 with VMWare Fusion 11.5.1

Answer (score 0):

`vmnet-cli -c` is unable to recreate the networks. I guess jai is right, this is related with "Security & Privacy" settings. VMWare Fusion related settings are not cleaned up (like those in privacy->Microphone) after uninstalling VMWare. We need to do a clean reinstallation.

1. Delete VMWare Fusion with [AppCleaner](http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/)
2. Reboot your system and log in to let the OS clean up former settings in "Security & Privacy". (KEY POINT)
3. Install VMWare Fusion. This time vmnet1 and vmnet8 will be created successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I went to Mac **Security & Privacy > Allow apps download from** and fixed the issue.