# No Internet for VMware Fusion for Mac for a virtual Windows 10 machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, windows-virtual-pc

I have been facing this problem of no internet in the Windows 10 virtual machine. I am running VMWare Fusion on a Macbook Pro.
I have tried restarting Win10 VM, VMWareFusion, but nothing works.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After wasting close to 10 hours of restarting the machines, adding Network Adapters, etc and of course googling and searching here on StackOverflow,
Finally the following works.

(Your VMWare Fusion and Windows 10 VM can be running)

1. open Terminal in Mac. and run the following commands. (You might
   need to key in your credentials since they are 'sudo' commands)
2. "sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli
   --stop"
3. "sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --start"

Voila!! end of Problems!

Comment: Thank you.  I had to set the network adapter back to NAT instead of bridged in VMware also (I was testing both), then it took a few seconds to connect in the VM Windows, and the internet came online about 20 seconds later.

Comment: Was also toggling this option in my blind search for a solution. Did not remember the original setting. But NAT works as seen now.

Comment: I am having issues getting NAT working on VMware Fusion v12 and Mac v11 BigSur. Does anyone else have this issue?

https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Big-Sur-hosts-with-Fusion-Is-vmnet-dhcpd-vmnet8-leases-file/m-p/2298927/highlight/true#M140003https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Big-Sur-hosts-with-Fusion-Is-vmnet-dhcpd-vmnet8-leases-file/m-p/2298927/highlight/true#M140003https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Big-Sur-hosts-with-Fusion-Is-vmnet-dhcpd-vmnet8-leases-file/m-p/2298927/highlight/true#M140003

Answer (score 2):

I started experiencing this issue when upgraded my Mac Book Pro. I upgraded from **macOS Big Sur 11.5** to **macOS Big Sur 11.6**

When I opened up my VMWare Fusion and started my Ubuntu virtual machine I realized that the virtual machine no longer connects to the host machine's internet connection automatically.

**Here are the few things I first tried that did not work**

1. I restarted the Ubuntu virtual machine multiple times, but with no success.
2. I quit VMWare Fusion and started it again, but with no success.
3. I restarted my Mac Book multiple time, but with no success
4. I disconnected and connected multiple times to my wifi, but no success.
5. I ran the following command [to load vmmon kext manually](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Fusion-Discussions/Fusion-Will-Not-Launch/td-p/1832440#.YVl684ErVT8.link): `sudo kextload /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/kexts/vmmon.kext/` and restarted my Mac Book for the extensions to be enabled. Then I ran the following command as well: `kextstat | grep vm`

**Here are the last things I tried that finally made it work for me**:

First, I navigated to the VMWare Fusion application directory:

```
cd /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library
```

Next, I ran the command below to check the status of vmnet:

```
sudo vmnet-cli --status
```

I got the result below which showed that they were off:

```
DHCP service on vmnet1 is not running
Hostonly virtual adapter on vmnet1 is disabled
DHCP service on vmnet8 is not running
NAT service on vmnet8 is running
Hostonly virtual adapter on vmnet8 is disabled
Some/All of the configured services are not running
```

Next, I tried to stop and start it using the command below:

```
sudo vmnet-cli --stop 
sudo vmnet-cli --start
```

I got the output below from the operation:

```
Enabled hostonly virtual adapter on vmnet1
Started DHCP service on vmnet1
Started NAT service on vmnet8
Enabled hostonly virtual adapter on vmnet8
Started DHCP service on vmnet8
Started all configured services on all networks
```

But when I ran the command below to check the status of vmnet:

```
sudo vmnet-cli --status
```

I got the result below again which showed that they were off:

```
DHCP service on vmnet1 is not running
Hostonly virtual adapter on vmnet1 is disabled
DHCP service on vmnet8 is not running
NAT service on vmnet8 is running
Hostonly virtual adapter on vmnet8 is disabled
Some/All of the configured services are not running
```

Finally, I tried running the command from [jai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48085386/10907864):

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

**Note**: `spctl` is a command-line interface to the same security assessment policy subsystem that Gatekeeper uses. Like Gatekeeper, spctl will only accept Developer ID-signed apps and apps downloaded from the Mac App Store by default. It will reject apps signed with Mac App Store development or distribution certificates. You can read up more here: [macOS Code Signing In Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2206/_index.html)

Next, I **shut down** (not restarted) my Mac Book and then turned it on again. This time the Ubuntu virtual machine was able to connect to the host machine's internet connection automatically.

You can enable `spctl` again (which is what I did) using the command below:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

and watch to see if things are fine, else, you may have to disable again.

You can also check the status of `spctl` using the command below:

```
sudo spctl --status
```

**That's all**

Answer (score 0):

you may need to reset your adaptor first if it was previously used.
https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2009642

you can continue to run as voted answer

```
> sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --stop 
> sudo /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmnet-cli --start
```